# SDL.NET SDL_Flip() equivalent

Tags: sdl, sdl.net

SDL has an [SDL_Flip() function](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip) for swapping screen buffers.

What is the equivalent in SDL.NET?  There is no Screen.Flip() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not called Flip, it's Update:

```
Video.Screen.Update();
```

Comment: For hardware that supports double-buffering, regular SDL distinguishes between SDL_Flip() and SDL_UpdateRect().  Are you saying that this distinction doesn't exist in SDL.NET?

Comment: The distinction is made through overloading. Update() with no arguments is Flip(). Update(Rectangle) is UpdateRect().